# PDF generating PHP based library among Mpdf,Tcpdf, Dompdf supporting PHP 8+

Tags: php, tcpdf, dompdf, mpdf

Which PDF generating PHP-based library among Mpdf, Tcpdf, and Dompdf fully supports PHP version 8 fully without any warnings or errors? And which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mPDF readme: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

```
PHP 8.0 is supported since mPDF v8.0.10
PHP 8.1 is supported as of mPDF v8.0.13
```